# Conditionally Render Markdown in MDX files

Tags: reactjs, astrojs, mdxjs

I want to conditionally render some markdown in an MDX file based on a prop passed from the parent.

I've tried this:

```
# Manufacturers Warranty

{props.nz && (
<>    
    ## New Zealand Made
    Our panels are New Zealand made in our Silverdale factory. 
</>
)}
```

This kind of works, but it renders the markdown as is, not converting it to HTML. The `##` markdown above renders as two hashes, not a heading.

Is conditional **markdown** possible in MDX, or once flicking to JSX am I stuck with JSX's HTML?

I'm using MDX in Astro - but I don't think that is impacting anything.

Comment: Could you import and render another component with the NZ Made content? `{props.nz && <NZMade />}`